# Pivot with Double Aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, aggregate

I have the SQL Below that works just fine in pivoting out my accounts according to their respective groups.  I just go back into my detail table and update the rows then delete the duplicates in the detail table.

## TempAccountRollup is my rollup table

## TempAccount is my detail table

A new requirement has come down for this code and I also need to get a count of the individual sections.  SO I will have..

```
ACCOUNT CONTRIBUTIONS  Donation  Gifts
1        205             20       50
```

What I want to have is:

```
ACCOUNT  CONTRIBUTION DONATION GIFTS CCOUNT DCOUNT GCOUNT
1           205          20     50     6      2      5
```

Is this possible with the code below?

Many thanks.

```
SELECT      ACCOUNTID, 
            [1] as Contribution, 
            [2] as Donation, 
            [3] as Gifts
INTO #TempAccountRollup
    FROM 
    (SELECT ACCOUNTID, amount,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY ACCOUNTID)
AS ROWNUM
FROM (SELECT accountID, namex , SUM(payment_amount) as amount
        from #TempAccount
        WHERE accountID IN (SELECT accountID from #TempAccount GROUP BY ACCOUNTID HAVING COUNT(accountID) > 5 
        )
        GROUP BY accountId, namex
        ) a ) test
PIVOT (SUM(amount) FOR RowNum IN ([1], [2], [3])) AS  pvt
```

Need to be a little more clear.  The code above produces the first sample.  Which is good.  I need it to produce the second sample.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it? What result do you get?

Comment: so where the other data came from? and why cant you add it like the other fields?

Comment: This Pivot works for my needs when it aggregates based on Contribution/Donation/Group.  I do now know how to make it COUNT in addition to SUM.  Thats the quandry that I have.    So I have sums by each category, but I also need to get the COUNTS of how many records went into each sum.  I may just have to hit the table again and do the COUNTS as a Pivot then marry the two results together.